# Getting error when creating a new customer account in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0, customer-account

I have installed a theme in Magento 2 when I create a new account for the customer it shows error. when I fill up customer info. and go for submitting it display error that is in [image]  please solve this problem.

Comment: enable developer mode and it will show the error message.
you may go to var/report folder and look for a file named as record number showed on screen . open that file and it will show error message

Comment: Please check var/log/exception.log file for error. or enable developer mode to see error on the page.

Comment: from where i can enable developer mode...??

Comment: if you have ssh access use this command magento deploy:mode:set developer
or goto app/etc/env.php and change MAGE_MODE' => 'default' to MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'

Comment: i have opened error the file from var/report folder, there are many error in this file

Comment: solve them one by one

Comment: ..or attach your report file content with your question. Question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Number error from your request is name of file from `/var/report`